# How to get pygame to update the display when I want it to?

Tags: python, graphics, pygame

I'm working on a simple graphics program that takes user commands in the console, and then has a pygame window display the results in the window. Up to now, I've had it working when I set up the commands hardcoded, but now that I'm trying to let it take user input it's running into issues.

Inside the game loop:

```
        while True:
            command = input("Enter a command: " + "\n"
                            "1: input" + "\n"
                            "2: apply transformation" + "\n"
                            "3: display pixels" + "\n"
                            "4: output" + "\n"
                            "5: basic translate" + "\n"
                            "6: basic scale" + "\n"
                            "7: basic rotate" + "\n"
                            "8: scale" + "\n"
                            "9: rotate" + "\n"
                            "Command:  ")

            command = int(command)

            if command == 1:
                num = Inputlines(datalines, num)
            elif command == 2:
                datalines = ApplyTransformation(matrix, datalines)
            elif command == 3:
                Displaypixels(datalines, num)
                pygame.display.update()
            elif command == 4:
                Outputlines(datalines, num)
            elif command == 5:
                Tx = int(input("Input a Tx value: "))
                Ty = int(input("Input a Ty value: "))
                matrix = BasicTranslate(Tx, Ty)
            elif command == 6:
                Sx = int(input("Input an Sx value: "))
                Sy = int(input("Input an Sy value: "))
                matrix = BasicScale(Sx, Sy)
            elif command == 7:
                angle = int(input("Input an Sx value: "))
                matrix = BasicRotation(angle)
            elif command == 8:
                Sx = int(input("Input an Sx value: "))
                Sy = int(input("Input an Sy value: "))
                Cx = int(input("Input a Cx value: "))
                Cy = int(input("Input a Cy value: "))
                matrix = Scale(Sx, Sy, Cx, Cy)
            elif command == 9:
                angle = int(input("Input an angle value: "))
                Cx = int(input("Input a Cx value: "))
                Cy = int(input("Input a Cy value: "))
                matrix = Rotate(angle, Cx, Cy)
            else:
                print("Not a valid command")
```

This is all basically just a way for the user to select functions from the console. The functions work for the most part, but the problem occurs when command = 3
It should call Displaypixels, which is just a function to add the pixels needed into the console. I then call pygame.display.update() to make the screen update, but nothing happens.

The screen says Not Responding. I can still continue the program through the console but nothing works. Perhaps I've misunderstood the purpose of pygame.display.update()?

Any help or constructive criticism is greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: you should check `Displaypixels` - it may not add pixel as you expect. BTW: you should use `pygame.event.get()` to get mouse/key events from system. On some systems if you don't get events then system may think that program hung and system may try to kill process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use pygame.event.get() to use mouse/any key from system.....sometime system kill process due to program hung so you should also check Display pixels in the System

Comment: Thanks! I replaced pygame.display.update() with pygame.event.get() and it worked!